# Calculating Time Python with broken Data in Column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

[image]

```html
Date     Time    TimeDelta Starttime Endtime
07.12.2019 12:42:06 00:00:10 07.12.2019 12:42 07.12.2019 12:42:16
07.12.2019 12:42:16 00:00:10 07.12.2019 12:42 07.12.2019 12:42:26
07.12.2019 12:42:26 01.01.1900 18:49 07.12.2019 12:42   ???
09.12.2019 07:32:20 00:00:10 09.12.2019 07:32 09.12.2019 07:32:30
09.12.2019 07:32:30 00:00:10 09.12.2019 07:32 09.12.2019 07:32:40
```

Hi, I try to calculate `time` from `dataframe` columns. `Starttime` and `Endtime` I want to calculate.

I have a `date and time` and can calculate them to starttime. In my `TimeDelta` Column i have mostly `hh:mm:ss` strings and sometimes this `01.01.1900` ... stuff. I need to calculate the `endtime`, but if i try

```
data["TimeDelta"] = pd.to_datetime(data["TimeDelta"], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

it tells me

> time data "" does not match format
>   '%H:%M:%S' (match)

how to convert them first in same format and then calculating them?

In Excel this is easy, how to do this in python?

Comment: I would use a pure python not pandas then add to dataframe column. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eirjjyP2qcQ) might help

Comment: What time delta is 01.0.1.1900 18:49 supposed to represent?

Comment: its a bug from the data...i have thousands of rows, sometimes this appear. its 18 hours and 49 minutes, the seconds are also there but hidden (copied from excel, sorry). i only need the time (HH:MM:SS) from these rows and then calculating i guess